# Approvals Inheritance for WSUS on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I'm running WSUS on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition build 9600. I have some troubles understanding how approvals inheritance works. According to [Microsoft Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939929(v=ws.10).aspx) when we approve multiple updates,these updates are not approved for the child groups unless we choose the `Apply to Children` option.

However when i approve multiple updates for a group, these updates are also approved for child groups even when the showed option for the subgroups is `Keep existing approvals`.

The approved updates become available for the clients in the subgroups and are displayed as inherited for the subgroups in the reports. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approval setting for the child groups are not actually changing in this scenario; they remain "Same as Parent".  It is just that when the approval is "Same as Parent" the console shows the parent setting with a note that the setting is inherited.

If you have explicitly changed the setting for a child group to anything other than "Same as Parent" then changing the setting for the parent group will not affect the child group.

The "Apply to Children" option changes the setting for all child groups to "Same as Parent".

Comment: Thank you. So if i understand correctly the approvals are inherited even if the showed option "Keep existing approvals" (in grey) is showed?

Comment: If "Keep existing approvals" is selected for a child group, then if the existing approval setting for the child group is inherited, the new approval setting will be inherited.  If the existing approval setting for the child group is not inherited, it will not be changed.